# Convert byte[] to String for HTML file

Tags: java, string, encoding, struts, arrays

I upload HTML file into DB as byte[] in blob column, and in another part I have to retrieve this file and display in textarea, I'm able to retrieve from DB as bytes and convert it into string, but when display its shows as encrypt format.

This is the struts application:

This is my jsp:

```
<tr>
 <td colspan="3" class="searchinput">   
      <html:textarea property="template" cols="100" rows="10" name="sendEmailForm">
      </html:textarea>
 </td>
</tr>
```

This is my form bean:

```
private String template = null;
public String getTemplate() {
   return template;
}

public void setTemplate(String template) {
   this.template = template;
}
```

This is my bean:

```
private byte[] templateContent = null;

public String getHtmlTemplateContent() {
  return templateContent.toString();
}

public byte[] getTemplateContent() {
  return templateContent;
}

public void setTemplateContent(byte[] templateContent) {
  this.templateContent = templateContent;
}

public void setTemplateContent(Object templateContent) {
  this.templateContent = (byte[])templateContent;
}
```

This is my action:

```
templatesDataBean = (TemplatesDataBean)SendEmailManager.getTemplate(action, actor, sendEmailBean);
sendEmailForm.setTemplate(new String(templatesDataBean.getHtmlTemplateContent()));
```

How can this can be solved? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it the possibility of encoding perhaps?

Comment: What do you mean by "encrypt data"?

Comment: Why do you need it as a byte[] in the first place? If it's HTML, a plain String should work all the way. Or doesn't your DB support storing string to the DB? ;)

Comment: shouldn’t this get encoded as UTF-8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `escapeXML` issue. By default it is `true`. I couldn't find nothing for Classic Struts. BTW, there is an `attribute` in Struts2 named `escape` for `<s:property>` element. However, you can achieve this using JSTL.

```
<tr>
 <td colspan="3" class="searchinput">   
      <textarea cols="100" rows="10">
           <c:out value="${sendEmailForm.template}" escapeXml="false"/>
      </textarea>
 </td>
</tr>
```

And I believe, even this should also work like charm.

```
<tr>
 <td colspan="3" class="searchinput">   
      <textarea cols="100" rows="10">
           ${sendEmailForm.template}
      </textarea>
 </td>
</tr>
```

In case it's some encoding issue, try instantiating your `String` using this constructor.

```
new String(templatesDataBean.getHtmlTemplateContent(), Charset.UTF-8)
```